# send cron output to a filename that is derived from the program name

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I tested the following with no luck. Any other ideas?

```
#cron test, I would like to generate a stderr logfile name based on $0, but $0 value is "/bin/bash"
#why do I want this? Because some program names are quite long, and for standardization
04 10 * * * ~/bin/cron-test >> /tmp/blah 2>>~/.cronlogs/$(basename $0)  # $0 is "/bin/bash"
05 10 * * * ~/bin/cron-test >> /tmp/blah 2>>~/.cronlogs/$(basename $1)  # $1 is empty?
06 10 * * * ~/bin/cron-test >> /tmp/blah 2>>~/.cronlogs/$(basename $2)  # $2 is empty?
```

Comment: What is this being run from?  What do you expect `$0`, `$1`, and `$2` to be?

Comment: Better change your script `~/bin/cron-test` to redirect its output. There you could use `$0` to get the script name.

Comment: Jesse_b, it is supposed to be a cron job. Looking at $1 and $2 is an attempt to work around the fact that $0 does not have the desired value "~/bin/cron-test". I was hoping that $1 would be "-c" and $2 would be "~/bin/cron-test", for example.

Comment: Bodo, I do not wish to hardcode output filenames into the script, I want to use stdout and stderr for testing and for non-cron use of the same scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a wrapper script to send the output to some particular place.

```
$ cat logwrap.sh
#!/bin/bash
logname=$(basename -- "$1").log
exec "$@" 2>> "~/.cronlogs/$logname"
```

Now, `logwrap.sh id some command` would run `some command` and send its output to `/work/logs/some.log`, so this would have its output sent to `/work/logs/cron-test.log`:

```
04 10 * * * /path/to/logwrap.sh ~/bin/cron-test
```

Comment: That's a good idea, for my particular purposes I would "exec 2> ~/.cronlogs/$logname";and let stdout pass through normally.

Comment: I think the "$@" should be on the "exec" line, took the liberty to edit it.

Comment: @reikred, yeah, it could be there, too, it seems to work. I don't think the difference matters much in this case. `exec` without a command sets the redirections for the rest of the script, so they're applied command that gets run by `"$@"`. With `exec "$@"`, the shell gets replaced by the command in `$@`, and again, of course the redirections apply to that since they're right there in the same command.

Comment: @reikred, The reason I had them separate was that originally, I had `eval "$@"` as the last command. Using `eval` would allow to pass a full shell command line to the script, with something like pipelines or such included. But it also invites extra quoting and your commands didn't need it anyway, so I left it out.